# How can I access to history service layer

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, editing, versioning, feature-service

I have set up a service which is provided by ArcGIS. I would like to have access to all the versions of the  parcel layer which are created during the edits I applied earlier to be able to gather information such as: the time of edit, the number of edits and the time...  Please tell me if there is an alternative way to access those information other than trying to access the versioned  parcels?

Comment: Are you able to write a python script that accomplishes this?  If so, have you considered publishing the script  as a GP service?

Comment: I have writen some python script . but for this problem I dont know that how  can do.if you know , Can you show me examples?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall it would be great if you show a example.